# Drain is starting to back up in basement

Tags: plumbing, basement, drain

I have an old house from the 60's. I have lived here for almost two years now. No flooding issues, previous owner had no flooding issues and my inspector said there were no signs of previous flooding. My condensate pump for my humidifier next to the drain starting running very loudly and I am going to replace it. I noticed on inspection that the drain nearby had visible water. I am surprised to see any water in the drain as my dehumidifier has not been running since October, maybe a couple times in November. The hose is connected to the dehumidifier. Should I consider this an emergency and call a plumber right away? I am honestly not sure how this drain works and there is no pump on it. I think it drains to somewhere outside the house, but it is a black box to me.

[image: drain]

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just a [trap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_(plumbing))?

Comment: Not to worry! As long as that water level stays where it is, all is well.

Comment: It could be a trap, I remember the inspector saying something about sewer gas and pouring vegetable oil down the drain (seemed odd to me) if the drain started to smell really bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the commenters said, I think you're looking at the result of normal trap function. Water is retained to the level of the "weir", or the high point along the bottom of the drain pipe. This acts as a plug and prevents sewer gas from escaping into the home.

It probably looked about like this before time and nature had their way:

[image]

Comment: Given the posted concern, is it worth mentioning that OP should be able to pour water in it to see that it drains, and doesn't overflow?

Comment: I suppose, but considering that it never *has* overflown, I didn't have much concern.

Comment: So long as the previous owners were not lying to me :) I think they were honest though and the inspector said the basement had no signs of previous water damage.

Comment: Also, if this is a trap, then that means all extra water just drains into a sewer which sounds ideal and is a relief!